# Firebase authentication without email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Currently, I am trying to develop a web portal where **I want to allow specific users to enter** in the site. This means I want to use specific username and password to enter my side without using any email address. How it is possible? I see that for custom login I have to use an authentication server and it is allowed in the F**unctions tab in Firebase**. But I have to purchase it. Is there any workaround available to create my custom login without an email.?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication has no `username-password` authentication. The best you can do is whenever user enters the user name you can append `@yourapp-com` to make the format like an email and use it with the password.

Use the same method when user tries to login, when they enter their username, append with that domain and use `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method. So technically you are using email and password (but the email cannot receive emails) but your users enter username and password only.

That was the easy work around but you can also store usernames and passwords in database. However make sure you properly hash the password in the database. You can use cloud functions to authenticate user. The auth flow would be like:

1. User enters username and password
2. A cloud function is triggered which then verifies the username and password
3. If the password matches, use the Admin SDK to generate a Custom Token and send it back to client
4. Use the `signInWithCustomToken` method and log the user in with that token.